Tests starting with r causing Jest to break on Windows
I am a windows user and I run jest like this:
jest .\r.test.js

But with this configuration:
module.exports = {
    preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
    transform: { '^.+\\.[tj]s?(x)?$': ['ts-jest', { rootDir: '.' }] },
    testMatch: ['**/tests/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.js'],
};

It breaks saying there are no tests, but if I run like:
jest r.test.js

It works.
I know it is the regex and that the input isn't being escaped.
How can I fix this so jest doesn't break whenever I use auto complete in PowerShell?
